# How do I represent the determinant (or the cross-product) as a linear transformation?

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations, determinant, cross-product

Let $\mathbf{v}$ be a vector:

$$
\mathbf{v}:=\pmatrix{x+ia\\y+ib\\z+ic}
$$

I am looking for an explicit $M$ such that:

$$
f(\mathbf{v})= \mathbf{v}^*M\mathbf{v}=\det\pmatrix{\sigma_x&\sigma_y&\sigma_z\\x&y&z\\a&b&c}
$$

Here $\sigma_x,\sigma_y,\sigma_z$ are the Pauli matrices.

---

Then, I would like to make the replacement $f(\mathbf{v})\to f(U\mathbf{v})$ and identify the invariance group of the determinant.

---

I have so far investigated writing $f(\mathbf{v})$ as follows:

$$
f(\mathbf{v})= \sigma_x \mathbf{v}^*M_x\mathbf{v} + \sigma_y \mathbf{v}^*M_y\mathbf{v}+ \sigma_z \mathbf{v}^*M_z\mathbf{v}
$$

Then finding 3 different $M_x,M_y,M_z$.

Comment: I don't understand (in particular) what are are $\sigma_x, \sigma_y, \sigma_z$, $U$... More generally, I don't catch your general motivation...

Comment: @JeanMarie I am trying to prove that preserving the determinant implies SU(3) symmetry. The sigmas are the Pauli matrices and $U$ is a linear transformation.

Comment: It wasn't evident that the $\sigma_i$ are Pauli matrices... How do you care for the dimensions of the matrix : do you consider it as $3 \times 3$...

Comment: @JeanMarie Yes, I consider $M$ to be $3\times 3$.

Comment: I don’t quite see how your equation is supposed to work. If the $\sigma_i$ are the usual $2\times2$ Pauli matrices, then the formal determinant on the right-hand side evaluates to a $2\times2$ matrix, but the left-hand side of the equation is a scalar.